# Room: Handling a list of child entities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have json received from a rest service which is comprised of some persons with each having a list of ids referencing some skills with each having a list of ids referencing some skill types:

```
{
    "person": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Biatrix",
            "age": 29,
            "skillIndices": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Oren",
            "age": 27,
            "skillIndices": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bill",
            "age": 52,
            "skillIndices": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        }
    ],
    "skill": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sword",
            "typeIndices": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Kong fu",
            "typeIndices": [
                3,
                4
            ]
        }
    ],
    "type": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Hattori"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Hanzō"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Shaolin"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Tai Chi Quan"
        }
    ]
}
```

For persisting this data to a Room database I have three entities and three dao's.

I need to somehow translate the ids to the real objects so when retrieving the data as LiveData using my repository **I'll get something like that, which I can use in my UI**:

```
{
    "person": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Biatrix",
            "age": 29,
            "skills": [
                [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sword",
                    "types": [
                        "Hattori",
                        "Hanzō"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Kong fu",
                    "types": [
                        "Shaolin",
                        "Tai Chi Quan"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Oren",
            "age": 27,
            "skills": [
                [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sword",
                    "types": [
                        "Hattori",
                        "Hanzō"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Kong fu",
                    "types": [
                        "Shaolin",
                        "Tai Chi Quan"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bill",
            "age": 52,
            "skills": [
                [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sword",
                    "types": [
                        "Hattori",
                        "Hanzō"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Kong fu",
                    "types": [
                        "Shaolin",
                        "Tai Chi Quan"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This needs of course (?) to happen under the Entity class as a Pojo, right? Tried to do this using the `@Relation` annotation, but can't seem to understand how to do.

**Here is the Entity for `Person`:**

```
package com.myapp.data.db.entity

import androidx.room.*

@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var name: String = 0,
    var age: Int = 0,
    var skillIndices: List<Int> = arrayListOf()
)
```

How do I manipulate this Entity so when asking for `Person` data, I'll get something like the above (second) dataset?

Comment: have you looked at https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/android-app-example-using-room-database-63f7091e69af - I only know a basic bit of android app development so i cannot answer your question but maybe it will help

Answer (score 2):

`skillIndices` should be its own inner-Entity, so that you could reference `var skillIndices: List<Skill>` inside `Person`.

Also do not forget to `@SerializeName("skill")` the field `skillIndices` as it doesn't have the same name.

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var name: String = 0,
    var age: Int = 0,
    var skills: List<Skill> = arrayListOf()
)

@Entity(tableName = "skill")
data class Skill(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var name: String = 0,
    var types: List<String> = arrayListOf()
)
```

Comment: "`skillIndices` should be its own inner-Entity, so that you could reference `var skillIndices: List<Skill>` inside `Person`". Can you add an example of this?